Can we "simplify" the $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ module $M = \frac{\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]}{ Span\{ 1+t+t^2 \}}$?
Let $R = \mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ be the  Laurent polynomials ring over the integers. Consider the $R$-module $M = \frac{R}{ Span_R\{ 1+t+t^2 \}}$.
This paper  contains the following theorem

Proposition 2.4.   Assume that $M$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$-module.
There exists a pair $U, B$ of finitely generated abelian groups and monomorphisms $f, g: U \rightarrow B$ such that $M$ is isomorphic to
the infinite free product $$\cdots \oplus_U B \oplus_U B \oplus_U
 \cdots$$ with identical amalgamations $B \stackrel{g}{\leftarrow} U
 \xrightarrow{f} B$;

If I understand the theorem correctly, it implies that there exists  $n$ and $N$, such that $M \cong \frac{R^n}{ Span_R{ N} }$, such that every element $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ in the set $N$ has the form of $ v_i = a + b t$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ for every $i$. Is there an obvious way to see such $N$ exists?
